# Filter by date ignoring the time in DateTime object in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I am trying to filter a date using Symfony 5 query builder. But the `DateTime` object has time in it and the query builder uses the time in the query too.

In my controller, I am catching the `POST` variables submitted through the form and storing them in an array to pass into my repository.

```
$criteria['date'] = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->get('date'));
```

And in my repository, I am building the query as follows.

```
$qb->andWhere('quotation.date = :date');
$qb->setParameter('date', $criteria['date']);
```

The problem is the database table column has the data type `datetime`, so when filtering nothing comes up because the `DateTime` object created has a wrong time in it.

Is there a way to filter only using the date part in PHP or in the database?

Comment: Filter between `d\m\Y 00:00:00` and `d\m\Y 23:59:59`.

Comment: well `BETWEEN Y-m-d 00:00:00 and Y-m-d 23:59:59` would probably be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your strict comparison `=` by filtering between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59.

However, the answer I would recommend is using [beberlei/DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions).

> A set of extensions to Doctrine 2 that add support for functions available in MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQLite.

One of those function is `DATE` which cast your datetime into a date to help with comparing datetime as date.

You can install it with composer

`composer require beberlei/doctrineextensions`

And you just have to configure which function you want to implement in your project in the doctrine.yaml file.

In your case you just need the DATE function :

```
doctrine:
    #...
    orm:
        #...
        entity_managers:
            default:
                #...
                dql:
                    datetime_functions:
                        DATE: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Postgresql\Date
```

And now you should be able to use the `DATE` function:

```
$qb->andWhere('DATE(quotation.date) = DATE(:date)');
$qb->setParameter('date', $criteria['date']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way: You put a "!" before the format.

```
$criteria['date'] = \DateTime::createFromFormat('!d/m/Y', $request->get('date'));
```

This sets the time to 00:00. Without the exclamation mark, the current time is always taken.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to separate your `DateTime` object into `Date` and `Time`